# Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined Vue + Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, babeljs

I am trying to add Leaflet library source into my project, but I'm getting an error on statements.

```
window.L = exports;
```

Vue Import Statement, copy of leaflet folder is in my project src folder

```
import L from '@/leaflet/src/Leaflet'
```

The screenshot of the problem.

[image]

I've updated the vue, babel and webpack, but still the problem is not resolved, here is my configuration.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What is `exports`? Are you just trying to do `window.L = L`?

Comment: exports is a statement in entry file of leaflet library. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/Leaflet.js

Comment: I can see that babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd has been installed, check once is it working after putting that plugin in .babelrc file 
    plugins: ["transform-es2015-modules-umd"]